# Bash/Perl: Unicode processing issue during string substitution in .htm files

Tags: regex, bash, perl, unicode

I have a bash script that uses Perl's substitution operator to replace a string within all .htm files in a specified directory.

```
find $files_dir -name '*.htm' | while read line; do
    ReplaceString "$line"
done

function ReplaceString {
    perl -pi -e 's/string1/string2/g' "$1"
    rm -rf "$1.bak"
}
```

The problem is that some of the files contain Unicode characters (e.g. '').  When any Unicode character is present in a file, that file is not processed and no string replacement occurs. When I remove the Unicode from the file, the string replacement works.

I am looking for a way to make my program "Unicode aware" so that it can process any file whether it contains Unicode or not.

I've also tried using sed instead of Perl:

```
sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' "$1"
```

which gives me the same issue.

Non-working file example (trimmed down):

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=unicode"></head>
<style>
     <!-- 
     /* Font definitions (generated by MS Word) */
     @list l0:level3
     {mso-level-text:;}
      -->
</style>
<body>
     <p>string1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What encoding are the files that don't work in? perl should be unicode aware enough to work properly for most encodings I believe (though I suppose you might need to tell it about the encoding of the file in some cases I'm not sure).

Comment: The files that don't work are set to unicode encoding. The other files are windows-1252.

Comment: That's rather bizarre. Can you show an example of such non-working file, preferably trimmed to a couple of lines?

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding. Do you perhaps mean UTF-16le?

Comment: (If you don't know, how about giving the output of `head -c 16 file.html | od -t x1` for one of the file.)

Comment: Thanks ikegami, the output for all non-working files is: 
0000000 ff fe 3c 00 68 00 74 00 6d 00 6c 00 20 00 78 00
0000020

Comment: This is in fact UTF-16le. You probably want to convert such files to something sensible first, like UTF-8. Note `charset=unicode` is incorrect, this attribute specifies the encoding ("charset" is a misnomer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ikegami and n.m. pointed out, the .htm files (which were generated using Microsoft Word), were encoded in UTF-16le.  The Perl substitution operation was not understanding this encoding.

I solved the problem by using MS Word to save the non-working files with UTF-8 encoding.